# Check permissions facebook app

Tags: javascript, facebook, typescript

I am trying to use the facebook API to get permissions to post to a users wall.

- I ask them permission, if they click 'Not Now', I want it to return to my page.
- If they say ok, a custom popup (facebookPopup) appears.

Below is what happens if they clcik a 'Share' button

```
public CheckPermissions() {
        var permsNeeded = ['publish_stream'];

        // Function that checks needed user permissions
        FB.api('/me/permissions', function (response) {
            var permsArray = response.data[0];
            var permsToPrompt = [];
            for (var i in permsNeeded) {
                if (permsArray[permsNeeded[i]] == null) {
                    permsToPrompt.push(permsNeeded[i]);
                }
            }              
                if (permsToPrompt.length > 0) {
                    promptForPerms(permsToPrompt);
                }
                else {
                   facebookPopup(response);
                }
            } );
        // Re-prompt user for missing permissions
        var promptForPerms = function (perms) {
                FB.login(function (response) {
                CheckPermissions();
                }, { scope: perms.join(',') });
        }
    }
```

The problem i'm having is that if they click 'Not Now', it keeps reprompting them because I am calling CheckPermissions() and it hits (permsToPrompt). I only want them to be repromted if they click the 'Share' button again.

Comment: Why was this tagged with TypeScript?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, should have been Javascript

Answer (score 1):

Here's something you can use:

```
module facebook {
    var grantedPermissions: { [permission: string]: number };

    function checkPermissions(callback?: Function): void {
        FB.api("/me/permissions", function (response): void {
            grantedPermissions = response.data[0];

            if (callback) { 
                callback();
            }
        });
    }

    export function init(): void {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response): void {
            if (response.status === "conntected") {
                checkPermissions();
            }
        });
    }

    export function hasPermission(permission: string): boolean {
        return grantedPermissions[permission] == 1;
    }

    export function getPermission(permission: string, callback?: Function): void {
        if (hasPermission(permission)) {
            if (callback) {
                callback();
            }

            return;
        }

        FB.login(function(response): void {
            checkPermissions(function() {
                if (callback && hasPermission(permission)) {
                    callback();
                }
            });
        }, { scope: permission });
    }
}
```

When you start the page call:

```
facebook.init();
```

Then you can use it this way:

```
button.addEventListener("click", function(event: Event): void {
    getPermission("publish_stream", fucntion() { 
        // do what ever you want here with the publish_stream permission granted
    });
});
```

Please keep in mind that this code is untested, I just wrote it, and it does not implement the entire login flow...

Hope this helps.

Comment: Looks like facebook has removed publish_stream permission and merged it with publish_action. That means you need to add the permission in your app and get facebook review approval now.

P.S. God knows where facebook is going with this. Even to allow user to share an image with some text, so much complex coding and including the facebook SDK is a must. It is so so easy with Google+ though :(